# What does it mean when a flag message appears faded/gray?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, flags

Earlier today, I saw a post in the flag queue that had an automatic low quality flag and a couple of "not an answer" flags on it.

However, the flag message of the low quality flag ("Low answer quality score [x]") appeared to be sort of faded, or grayed out. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags previously seen to and dismissed, will, if the post is flagged again, be faded.

With the previous flag reasons greyed out it allows you to check out what the previous raises were so that you can see if the state is changing or getting worse.