# Why are review reasons gray for some posts?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean when a flag message appears faded/gray?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118092/what-does-it-mean-when-a-flag-message-appears-faded-gray)

I was reviewing some posts when I noticed that the flag/close reason was gray on some of them:

[image]

Does the gray text signify something?

Comment: Relatively sure it's because you've seen the flag before, or at least the post in the flag queue before.